# Get Tap handling actions on specific parts of uiimage view in iOS

Tags: ios

I have an image view in which the image is having various small child images in it. But the thing is I am getting this entire image(parent image with child images) as one single image from a Web Service at run time.

How can I handle taps on these child images(pasted or attached on the main image) after the parent image is received at run time?

I know I can add `uiview` on those small images and then handle their taps. But the problem is I dont know how to extract coordinates of child images in parent image, hence can't place `uiviews` on the child images...

Is the solution to this problem even possible? I am quite stuck.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Sorry in advance ,if the question is vague. I'm new to iOS development.

Comment: Hi Dhruv... If you are getting a single image i.e parent and child image on a single image then it is not possible to do this....else you can ask server side developer to send parent and child images separately and set them with tag and do the desired task...

Answer (score 1):

Get the point of the gesture:

```
CGPoint loc = [tap locationOfTouch:0 inView:imageView];
```

Then you can check the `loc` againts the cordinates of the child images, that is if you know child images' cordinates in the parent image.